# Python regex re.compile search failing

Tags: python, regex

I used `https://regex101.com/#python` to build the below patterns for a regx search. And although it works fine in the builder site, it seems to be failing in my python script. The traceback suggests `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`

```
raw = [u'\n#\n# ARIN WHOIS data and services are subject to the Terms of Use\n# available at: https://www.arin.net/whois_tou.html\n#\n# If you see inaccuracies in the results, please report at\n# https://www.arin.net/public/whoisinaccuracy/index.xhtml\n#\n\n\n#\n# Query terms are ambiguous.  The query is assumed to be:\n#     "n 132.245.55.8"\n#\n# Use "?" to get help.\n#\n\n#\n# The following results may also be obtained via:\n# https://whois.arin.net/rest/nets;q=132.245.55.8?showDetails=true&showARIN=false&showNonArinTopLevelNet=false&ext=netref2\n#\n\nNetRange:       132.245.0.0 - 132.245.255.255\nCIDR:           132.245.0.0/16\nNetName:        MICROSOFT\nNetHandle:      NET-132-245-0-0-1\nParent:         NET132 (NET-132-0-0-0-0)\nNetType:        Direct Assignment\nOriginAS:       \nOrganization:   Microsoft Corp (MSFT-Z)\nRegDate:        2011-06-22\nUpdated:        2013-08-20\nRef:            https://whois.arin.net/rest/net/NET-132-245-0-0-1\n\n\n\nOrgName:        Microsoft Corp\nOrgId:          MSFT-Z\nAddress:        One Microsoft Way\nCity:           Redmond\nStateProv:      WA\nPostalCode:     98052\nCountry:        US\nRegDate:        2011-06-22\nUpdated:        2015-10-28\nComment:        To report suspected security issues specific to \nComment:        traffic emanating from Microsoft online services, \nComment:        including the distribution of malicious content \nComment:        or other illicit or illegal material through a \nComment:        Microsoft online service, please submit reports \nComment:        to:\nComment:        * https://cert.microsoft.com.  \nComment:        \nComment:        For SPAM and other abuse issues, such as Microsoft \nComment:        Accounts, please contact:\nComment:        * abuse@microsoft.com.  \nComment:        \nComment:        To report security vulnerabilities in Microsoft \nComment:        products and services, please contact:\nComment:        * secure@microsoft.com.  \nComment:        \nComment:        For legal and law enforcement-related requests, \nComment:        please contact:\nComment:        * msndcc@microsoft.com\nComment:        \nComment:        For routing, peering or DNS issues, please \nComment:        contact:\nComment:        * IOC@microsoft.com\nRef:            https://whois.arin.net/rest/org/MSFT-Z\n\n\nOrgTechHandle: MRPD-ARIN\nOrgTechName:   Microsoft Routing, Peering, and DNS\nOrgTechPhone:  +1-425-882-8080 \nOrgTechEmail:  IOC@microsoft.com\nOrgTechRef:    https://whois.arin.net/rest/poc/MRPD-ARIN\n\nOrgAbuseHandle: MAC74-ARIN\nOrgAbuseName:   Microsoft Abuse Contact\nOrgAbusePhone:  +1-425-882-8080 \nOrgAbuseEmail:  abuse@microsoft.com\nOrgAbuseRef:    https://whois.arin.net/rest/poc/MAC74-ARIN\n\n\n#\n# ARIN WHOIS data and services are subject to the Terms of Use\n# available at: https://www.arin.net/whois_tou.html\n#\n# If you see inaccuracies in the results, please report at\n# https://www.arin.net/public/whoisinaccuracy/index.xhtml\n#\n\n']

pattern_strings = ['address:(.*?)(?=\\nphone:)', 'Address(.*?)(?=\\nRegDate:)']
pattern_string = '|'.join(pattern_strings)
address_t = re.compile(pattern_string)
address_t2 = address_t.search(raw)            
if address_t2.group(0):
    address = address_t2.group(0)
if address_t2.group(1):
    address = address_t2.group(1)
```

Comment: replace \\ with \ in your regex.

Comment: nope that doesnt work, and is needed to stop at the literal `'\nphone:` or `\nRegDate:`

Comment: `\nphone:` isn't literally `\nphone:`, it's a newline followed by `phone:`. Try `print(raw[0])` to see for yourself.

Comment: if you look at the data im parsing with the regx. youll see im matching literally `\nAddress:` to `\nRegDate:`. Try the code

Comment: You might find https://bitbucket.org/richardpenman/pywhois useful or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30820371/re-split-return-none-in-function-but-normaly-works-ok/30820396#30820396

Comment: `\nRegdate:` in your raw string is not a literal `\n`. It's a newline. Then again, it's also that in your regex (now).

Comment: Just simplify that to [`pattern_string = r'(?i)address:(.*?)(?:\s+(?:phone|RegDate):)' // 
address_t = re.compile(pattern_string, re.S)`](https://ideone.com/4qiaNN).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second alternative expression, `Address(.*?)(?=\\nRegDate:)`, you seem to want `.` to match any character, including newline, which is not its normal meaning.

Try this:

```
address_t = re.compile(pattern_string, re.DOTALL)
```

Comment: Spot on Rob, thank you for taking the time to look the question and available data.

Comment: You are welcome, but it took me longer than it should have because your test program wasn't actually your test program. I had to fix two syntax errors in order for it to run. In future, please **copy-paste** (don't retype or summarize) your **entire** (not skipping `import`, for example) short program that demonstrates the error. Here is the program I actually tested: http://ideone.com/dYYJHc .  See [ask] and [mcve] for more tips on asking excellent questions.